# Image/DIV Element Toggle Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below is a working example when you click the image it opens webpage browser in fullscreen, HOWEVER I don't know how to make the javascript toggle fullscreen mode when clicking image again.

**So the script needs to open full screen mode when clicking image the first time, then exit full screen mode when clicking the same image the second time.**

HTML:

```
    <h1>Click image to toogle fullscreen mode</h1>
    <img id="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/lPZh57Y.png" alt="logo" />
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    var viewFullScreen = document.getElementById("logo");
    if (viewFullScreen) {
       viewFullScreen.addEventListener("click", function () {
           var docElm = document.documentElement;
           if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
               docElm.requestFullscreen();
           }
           else if (docElm.msRequestFullscreen) {
               docElm.msRequestFullscreen();
           }
           else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
               docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
           }
           else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
               docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
           }
       }, false);
   }

  var cancelFullScreen = document.getElementById("logoCONFLICT");
  if (cancelFullScreen) {
     cancelFullScreen.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
     }, false);
  }   
})();
```

Comment: Add a class to the img when You go fullscreen, you are selecting logoCONFLICT id but there is not in the DOM so You must dynamically add it when You go into fullscreen

Comment: Thanks I release that logoCONFLICT leads to nothing, it conflicted when I tried just 'logo'.

I was hoping for someone to post some code to solve the issue, since my javascripts skills are lacking. :(

Comment: Everything will work fine You will need just to add a fullscreen class when You enter fullscreen and remove it when you exit fullscreen, You are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to keep track when you request the full screen & exit full screen calls. And run the appropriate code based on this value. You don't need two separate click listeners for this. Just another [if else statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

```
<script>
(function () {
    var viewFullScreen = document.getElementById("logo");
    var isFullScreen;

    if(viewFullScreen) {
        viewFullScreen.addEventListener("click", function () {

                    if(!isFullScreen) {

                        var docElm = document.documentElement;
                        if(docElm.requestFullscreen) docElm.requestFullscreen();
                        else if(docElm.msRequestFullscreen) docElm.msRequestFullscreen();
                        else if(docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
                        else if(docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();

                        isFullScreen = true;

                    } else {

                        if(document.exitFullscreen) document.exitFullscreen();
                        else if(document.msExitFullscreen) document.msExitFullscreen();
                        else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) document.mozCancelFullScreen();
                        else if(document.webkitCancelFullScreen) document.webkitCancelFullScreen();

                        isFullScreen = false;
                    }

                }, false);
    }
})();
</script>
```

Haven't tested it but should work. A better way would be to detect the fullscreen status initially and listen for the changes [as described here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/). Instead of attempting to keep track of the status yourself.

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll read the links you provided since it still doesn't quite work.
[Your Fix](http://www.webdevey.com/so/fullscreen/fix1.html)

Comment: @rwcommand The if statement was wrong.. should be `if( !isFullScreen )` instead of `if( isFullScreen )`. But definitely have a look at the link, that should help you to build a more robust solution. The problem with this quick-fix is that if someone enters the site already in full screen it won't work properly. Neither when someone goes to full screen mode through any other method than clicking on the image e.g.: through the browser menu.